# Doctrine 2 - persisting entities in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've been struggling with this for some hours now and have read through the [Doctrine documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) and more [documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) but I'm still struggling.

I have two tables.  My "lookups" table is the owner (many) in the relationship with the "lookup_statuses" table (one).  There are multiple different statuses that a particular lookup can be in.

This is (I think) a uni-directional one-to-many relationship.

In code I search the lookup_statuses table and get back an object that matches the slug I need.  I call setLookupStatus on my lookup entity and try to persist it.  I get the error '**A new entity was found through the relationship**'.

I used the doctrine reverse engineering to start off my domain model but I just cannot work out how to properly implement this relationship.

My LookupStatuses class (one) looks like this:

```
namespace App\Lib\Domain\Datalayer;

/**
 * LookupStatuses
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="lookup_statuses")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LookupStatuses
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Lib\Domain\Datalayer\Lookups", mappedBy="lookupStatus", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $lookups;
}
```

And my Lookups table (many) looks like this:

```
namespace App\Lib\Domain\Datalayer;

/**
 * Lookups
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="lookups", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_4CEC819D037A087", columns={"lookup_status_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_4CEC8194D39DE23", columns={"camera_event_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Lookups
{
   /**
     * @var \App\Lib\Domain\Datalayer\LookupStatuses
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Lib\Domain\Datalayer\LookupStatuses", inversedBy="lookups", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lookup_status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $lookupStatus;
}
```

Here are the versions of the stack I'm using:

```
"php": ">=5.4.0",
"laravel/framework": "5.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.4.0",
```

Please can somebody help me unravel this so that my use case will work.  I want to:

1. Look up a status in the lookup_statuses code
2. Call setLookupStatus() on my lookup entity with the object I get
3. Persist the lookup to save the new status code

---- update : including code ----

This is sample code:

```
$lookupStatusesService = ServiceFactory::getInstance('LookupStatuses');

$status = $lookupStatusesService->findOne(['slug' => $slug], true);

$cameraEventService = ServiceFactory::getInstance('CameraEvents');

$cameraEvent = $cameraEventService->findOne(['uuid' => $uuid], true);

$unicodeLookupService = ServiceFactory::getInstance('UnicodeLookups');

$unicodeLookup = $unicodeLookupService->findOne(['cameraEvent' => 

$cameraEvent->getId()], true);

$unicodeLookup->setLookupStatus($status);

EntityManager::persist($unicodeLookup);

EntityManager::flush();
```

Findone() builds up querybuilder where clauses and returns

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for 3 hours with this I solved it on the walk to my car from the office.

The problem is that I was using *Memcached*.

The object I was getting from my findby was a Doctrine Entity, but was returned from cache instead of coming from Doctrine.  That's why Doctrine thought it was new.  If I insist on getting a fresh result from the database the code works.

I suspect that because I'm using a unidirectional relationship the @OneToMany in LookupStatuses is superfluous.

Comment: @julestruong Sorry, no, this was too long ago.  Looking at what I wrote the solution was I'd suggest reading clean out of the database instead of using a cached representation.